# How to prevent transparent world UI elements from hiding post processing?

Tags: unity, unity-ui, post-processing, bloom

I have transparent world ui elements in my game like so:[image: image of issue]

What I've been noticing is that post processing through transparent elements is nonexistent, even though other parts of the scene work with post processing perfectly fine. I've searched this issue up countless times but couldn't seem to find any solution. Does anyone know if this is even fixable? (using Unity 2021.3.5f1)

Comment: Is the processing hidden, or is the translucent blue backing just darkening the yellow enough that it no longer reaches the brightness threshold to bloom?

Comment: It does seem to be that the translucent blue is just darkening the yellow. Is there a way to fix this? (I changed emission from 5.5 to 7.6 and it was just visible through the element)

Comment: @DMGregory do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Your question already asks for solutions. You never need to post a comment repeating the question. When someone has a solution to share with you, you'll know because they will post it as an answer post below.

Comment: My guess would be that the values under and passed through the transparency are clamped to 1 and eliminating the bloom factor.  Increasing the emission only helped insofar as to make the bloom radius larger and cover more pixels. I can tell you the issue is a clamp in one of the built-in shaders or a compositing render-target clamping the output.  Either way, I am not sure a public general solution does exist.